# Why does git pull stop working after a config sync in Drupal 8?

Tags: git, github, drupal-8

I had to export a config sync from my Drupal 8 localhost, in order to import it into my production server(cpanel) version. I did this in localhost's CLI with this:

```
drush cim sync
```

To do this I had to add the config/sync directory's files to my git repo.
I did this, and git pulled it to my cpanel via SSH/CLI.
This worked and the Drupal site was fixed/loaded fine on my cpanel.

But since then, further git pulls on the production server fail:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
```

(lists all the config / sync files)

The files lsited in the error were already added to git repo and are up to date, so I'm not sure why cpanel's git pull flags them as being untracked.

How do I stop them being flagged and allow the git pull to successfully run?

EDIT: I removed the config/sync files from the cpanel and ran git pull again.

This time it also gave the same error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
```

Except this time the list was completely different, many lines, but here's some examples:

```
    vendor/symfony/translation/Resources/bin/translation-status.php
web/core/modules/serialization/src/Normalizer/SerializedColumnNormalizerTrait.php
web/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.css
web/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.css.map
web/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css
web/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css.map
web/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.css
web/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.css.map
web/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css
web/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css.map
web/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
web/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css.map
web/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

I really don't know what is happening with this anymore?

Comment: If you have hooks they could be making changes to the files during the pull process. Check in `.git/hooks/`.

Comment: Hi Schwern I checked .git/hooks/ and yes there are 11 hooks there, all ending in ".sample".
Should I delete those completely or manage them in some way?


(Side note: has something changed in the last 3 weeks with either git or Drupal because I have another site built in almost identical way that gave me none of these errors?)

Comment: .sample ones are there by default and don't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

The fix for me was to work through the git pull error list and remove all the untracked files from my live server's directories.

Some quick examples of listed untracked files that I removed from cpanel/file manager:

```
web/modules/contrib/extra_field/LICENSE.txt
web/modules/contrib/extra_field/README.txt
web/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css
web/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css.map
vendor/symfony/translation/Resources/bin/translation-status.php
web/core/modules/serialization/src/Normalizer/SerializedColumnNormalizerTrait.php
```

Once I removed all these files, I could then successfully git pull on the cpanel via SSH:

```
git pull origin master
```

After this git pull my production (cPanel) site was loading with correct appearance, updated css, etc.

I'm still not 100% certain why config export was required on this occasion as an almost identical deployment 3 weeks ago did not require it.

However, on this occasion it was required and the resulting git pull issues were resolved as per this answer.